# "reach further" or "go beyond"

Tags: sentence-choice

> Bilingualism allows students to dream bigger and **reach further**.

In this sentence, would "go beyond" be better ? Which one is more formal? (I am writing an essay.)

Thank you guys.

Comment: IMO, I don't think one is more 'formal' than the other. Both sound pretty fine.

Comment: you can always merge them into "go beyond their reach"

Answer (score 3):

In your example,

> **reach further**

is the correct phrase to use since you are trying to express **aspirational ambition**.
**Go beyond** would should awkward to a non-native speaking ear, since it raises the question

> Go beyond ***what***?

Your sentence is perfectly understandable, but strictly speaking, for parallel construction you might use

> Bilingualism allows students **to** dream bigger and **to** reach further

As an aside, **bilingualism**, although a fine word, sounds very bulky

> Knowing two languages
>   Being fluent in two languages
>   Being bilingual

might be better options.